# How to decode QR code using metaio SDK 4.5

Tags: android, qr-code, augmented-reality

I am a beginner in android development and just obtained metaio SDK 4.5 , I would like to develop an application where it reads QR code (already created by external QR generator with string "metaioman"), obtain the string and load the 3D model of metaio man.

I have been modifying tutorial 3 to have only just one button and the following code :
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame() 
    {
        super.onDrawFrame();

```
    if (metaioSDK != null)
    {
        // get all detected poses/targets
        TrackingValuesVector poses = metaioSDK.getTrackingValues();

        //if we have detected one, attach our metaio man to this coordinate system Id
        if (poses.size() != 0)
            {
               mMetaioMan.setCoordinateSystemID(poses.get(0).getCoordinateSystemID());
            }               
    }
}
```

So the question is where do i put the poses.get(0).getAdditionalValues()  to obtain the equivalent string to the QR ? or is this logic flawed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not used metaio, but have used the open-source zxing barcode library. It works great, give it a try.
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: I try to use it before but my project is augmented reality and metaio helps me alot in dealing with models.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an [example Android Activity](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/16240/how-to-read-qr-code) that reads QR code and displays the result in a `TextView`.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.